# f:setPropertyActionListener for items in p:menu (Primefaces)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Can you show me how to add f:setPropertyActionListener for Programmatic Menu using Primefaces in jsf

```
public MenuBean() {  
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();  

        //First submenu  
        Submenu submenu = new Submenu();  
        submenu.setLabel("Dynamic Submenu 1");  

        MenuItem item = new MenuItem();  
        item.setValue("Dynamic Menuitem 1.1");  
        item.setUrl("#");  
        submenu.getChildren().add(item);  

        model.addSubmenu(submenu);  

        //Second submenu  
        submenu = new Submenu();  
        submenu.setLabel("Dynamic Submenu 2");  

        item = new MenuItem();  
        item.setValue("Dynamic Menuitem 2.1");  
        item.setUrl("#");  
        submenu.getChildren().add(item);  

        item = new MenuItem();  
        item.setValue("Dynamic Menuitem 2.2");  
        item.setUrl("#");  
        submenu.getChildren().add(item);  

        model.addSubmenu(submenu);  
    }
```

and

```
 <p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this programatically it is as simple as:

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.addActionListener(listener);
```

Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: i want to add something like <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.processValue}" value="#{someColumnItem}" /> but in programatically

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.faces.event.ActionListener;
import com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SetPropertyActionListenerImpl;
...
//setPropertyActionListener
                ValueExpression target = expFact.createValueExpression(elCtx, "#{TesterBean.someProperty}", String.class);
                ValueExpression value  = expFact.createValueExpression(strProperty, String.class);
                ActionListener handler = new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl( target , value );
                newCommandLink.addActionListener(handler);
```